# How to determine .NET cookie path

Tags: .net, asp.net, cookies, httpcookie

I am writing a .NET application that uses cookies to store a login token.  I'd like the user to be able to log into multiple installations of this application on the same server (let's say `jacob.local/Devel` and `jacob.local/Stable`), so I want to set the Path property for the cookies appropriately.  Currently I'm using `Request.ApplicationPath` but am running into trouble when the user visits the site with a different case than what I've set up in IIS.

For example, the user visits `jacob.local/stable` -- the cookie's path will be `/Stable`, which the browser doesn't send back to me since it can't know that IIS is case insensitive.

Do I have to parse apart the whole query string myself, or is there already a function for figuring out what the path of the application is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following trick grabs the application path with casing matched to the one specified in the URL of the current request.

```
Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Remove(Request.ApplicationPath.Length)
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks.

Comment: The problem with this is that you have to be careful never to use Request.Application path when forming URLs throughout your application. you must use this trick not just when sending the cookie but also when generating any absolute or site-relative URL